# What might be causing a "ghost" table name in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

When I run:

```
cqlsh> SELECT * FROM system_schema.tables WHERE keyspace_name = 'demo_fds';
```

I see the table name of interest (`afifarmrecord`):

```
      demo_fds |   afifarmrecord |                   0.01 | {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'} | null |         | {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompa
ctionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'} | {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'} |                1 |               
         0.1 |                    0 |           {} | {'compound'} |           864000 | 571c9960-3bba-11eb-93dc-9726102541d7 |               2048 |                           0 |          
      128 |                  0 |      99PERCENTILE
      demo_fds |      shactivity |                   0.01 | {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'} | null |         | {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompa
ctionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'} | {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'} |                1 |               
         0.1 |                    0 |           {} | {'compound'} |           864000 | 57eb8220-3bba-11eb-93dc-9726102541d7 |               2048 |                           0 |          
      128 |                  0 |      99PERCENTILE
      demo_fds |  shrumandeating |                   0.01 | {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'} | null |         | {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompa
ctionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'} | {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'} |                1 |               
         0.1 |                    0 |           {} | {'compound'} |           864000 | 581c0800-3bba-11eb-93dc-9726102541d7 |               2048 |                           0 |          
      128 |                  0 |      99PERCENTILE
      demo_fds |        sxrecord |                   0.01 | {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'} | null |         | {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompa
ctionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'} | {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'} |                1 |               
         0.1 |                    0 |           {} | {'compound'} |           864000 | 585e1a10-3bba-11eb-93dc-9726102541d7 |               2048 |                           0 |          
      128 |                  0 |      99PERCENTILE
```

However, the behavior is different between `afifarmrecord` and another empty table:

```
cqlsh> select * from demo_fds.afifarmrecord   limit 20;
'afifarmrecord' not found in keyspace 'demo_fds'
cqlsh> select * from demo_fds.shactivity   limit 20;

 mark | timestamp | serializedrecord
------+-----------+------------------

(0 rows)
```

One is merely empty, but the other seems to not exist. I'm trying to figure out why this might be happening, as I believe I'm creating all tables in the same way, so it is odd that only one of them has this symptom.

**Update 1: status of cluster and keyspace**

```
$ nodetool describecluster
Cluster Information:
        Name: Test Cluster
        Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSnitch
        DynamicEndPointSnitch: enabled
        Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
        Schema versions:
                24104e25-be79-3da1-a8b7-d7b0be9034b8: [127.0.0.1]


$ nodetool status demo_fds
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Token                                    Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  3.03 GiB   100.0%            e0bbc831-8686-43a6-b99c-8ea5596c8581  3840369556391221198                      rack1
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are creating tables programmatically based on the creation time of the tables (`id` column):

```
afifarmrecord  - 571c9960-3bba-11eb-93dc-9726102541d7 = 6:08:27am PST
shactivity     - 57eb8220-3bba-11eb-93dc-9726102541d7 = 6:08:28am PST
shrumandeating - 581c0800-3bba-11eb-93dc-9726102541d7 = 6:08:29am PST
sxrecord       - 585e1a10-3bba-11eb-93dc-9726102541d7 = 6:08:29am PST
```

The table ID is a version 1 UUID which includes a timestamp of when it was created. In the case above, all the table IDs were created on December 11 (Pacific).

Due to the closeness of their creation time, it leads me to believe you were programatically creating tables in your cluster without checking first that each individual DDL statement has propagated successfully across the cluster before invoking the next DDL update.

As such, it leads to a schema disagreement which is what I suspect is happening here. When you query a node in the cluster, it doesn't know about the table and so returns the "not found" error.

You will need to resolve the schema disagreement usually by performing a rolling restart. You can check that all nodes are in agreement with the `nodetool describecluster` command and ensure that there is only one schema version across all nodes. Cheers!

Comment: This is a good callout, Erick.  I always say to folks "Don't build Cassandra DDL into your code; despite all the online examples you find which show to do it that way."

Comment: You're right that I am building it in the code. I had some pretty appealing reasons for doing this, but it is good to know there are some gotchas I should be aware of. Additionally, there is only one node - I guess I'm effectively running a test cluster. This is a tiny system at the moment. I updated the status information in my question above. Any other ideas or clarifications would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: It still strikes me as one DDL statement rolling over the top of another. If you were using the Java driver, you'd need to make a call to `checkSchemaAgreement()`. But as @Aaron agrees, I still wouldn't do it. It's not worth the trouble you'd run into. Cheers!

Comment: After some time away, I tried dropping the keyspace (luckily it was a test key space!) and tried recreation. So far, it seems to be working normally, so I'm not sure what went wrong the last time. Anyway, I'll keep an eye out and post back if I find anything.